# No qualifying bean of type 'springfox.documentation.schema.TypeNameExtractor'

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jhipster, springfox

I'm trying to implement Swagger using the [JHipster implementation](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster/tree/master/jhipster-framework/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/config/apidoc) as reference into my Kotlin application.

However, when I run my tests, I get the following error for most of my tests (these tests work fine if I remove this swagger code):

```
Caused by:
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pageableParameterBuilderPlugin' defined in class path resource [com/application/config/apidoc/SwaggerPluginsAutoConfiguration$SpringPagePluginConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pageableParameterBuilderPlugin' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springfox.documentation.schema.TypeNameExtractor' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

My `SwaggerPluginsAutoConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@ConditionalOnBean(Docket::class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(SwaggerAutoConfiguration::class)
class SwaggerPluginsAutoConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnClass(Pageable::class)
    class SpringPagePluginConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean
        fun pageableParameterBuilderPlugin(typeNameExtractor: TypeNameExtractor,
                                           typeResolver: TypeResolver): PageableParameterBuilderPlugin {
            return PageableParameterBuilderPlugin(typeNameExtractor, typeResolver)
        }
    }
}
```

The `SwaggerAutoConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@ConditionalOnClass(ApiInfo::class, BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration::class, Servlet::class, DispatcherServlet::class)
@Profile(value = [SPRING_PROFILE_SWAGGER])
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration::class)
class SwaggerAutoConfiguration(applicationProperties: ApplicationProperties) {
...
}
```

If I include the `swagger` profile in my tests application config file, the tests pass.  However, if the profile isn't present, the tests fail with the error above.  I'm not sure why Spring is trying to configure swagger if the profile isn't set.

How can I set this up, so that the configuration doesn't try to load if the profile isn't specified?

Comment: See if adding `@ComponentScan({"springfox.documentation.schema"})` works until you figure out the proper way to configure this.

Comment: Looking at the Java doc, you may rather add `@Import(springfox.documentation.schema.configuration.ModelsConfiguration)` to your SwaggerPluginsAutoConfiguration class.

Comment: @Neo When I add `@Import(springfox.documentation.schema.configuration.ModelsConfiguration)` I get `Classifier 'ModelsConfiguration' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here`.  The issue I'm having only happens on my existing tests.  The application starts up normally.  Can I do something in the JUnit tests to inject the `TypeNameExtractor` bean?

Comment: I have updated the question based on my latest findings relating to the `swagger` profile.